# Dispatch request for all elements of an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array of payloads. Now, I want to dispatch requests for all the elements of the array when a button is clicked. I am trying to map over the array and send all requests but, somehow that only sends request for the last element.

My Array:

```
arr = [first_payload, second_payload, third_payload]
```

My Button:

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    <Button
        text="Generate"
        variant="primary"
        onClick={()=>{
            arr.map(item =>
                {
                    dispatch(
                        fetchConfigAsync.request({
                            item
                        })
                    )
                }
            )
        }} 
    />
```

My reducer class:

```
case fetchConfigAsync.successType:
     return {
         ...state,
         state: (state.Config.push(action.response))
    }
```

However, the above code called the request for only the last element in the array.

Comment: Wouldn't that make more sense to process single request with batched data, instead of hitting your endpoint with tons of requests?

Comment: The API is configured to take one payload only as input.

Comment: I would assume that you are using redux-saga as middleware, aren't you?

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk yes. I am using saga

Comment: Then you need to know that `takeLatest` literally means latest :)
Change it to `takeEvery`, it should help

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk Wow that fixed it. Thanks. I had not even added that part in the question. You must be a genius to be able to guess that.

Comment: @modov you are not the first one, that does this mistake :)